# Sigma finite measure

Tags: measure-theory

i'm doing an exercise and i'm struggling to conclude. It is has followed :

Let $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{A}, \mu         )$ be a measured space.
We define $\nu$ by:

$ \forall A \in \mathcal{A}, \nu(\mathcal{A}):= $ Sup $ \left\{  \mu(B);B  \in \mathcal{A}, B \subset \mathcal{A} \text{ and } \mu(B)< \infty \right\}$.

I showed that this defines a measure on $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{A} )$ but i now have to show that if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite then $\nu=\mu$.

What i tried is this :
$ \forall A \in \mathcal{A},\exists B_0 \in  \mathcal{A}, \mu(B_0)=  $ Sup $  \left\{  \mu(B);B  \in \mathcal{A}, B \subset \mathcal{A} \text{ and } \mu(B)< \infty \right\}=\nu(A)$

$ B_0 \subset A, \implies \mu(B_0) \leq \mu(A)$.
Then i want to use this

$ \mu(A)= \mu(B_0)+\mu(A \backslash B_0) $ because $\mu(B_0) < \infty$.

There problem i think is that here i want to say that since $\mu(B_0) < \infty$ and $\mu(A) < \infty$ then (i think this is wrong) $\mu(A \backslash B_0)< \infty$.

If this was correct i could say that since $B_0$ realise the supremum of $E= \left\{  \mu(B);B  \in \mathcal{A}, B \subset \mathcal{A} \text{ and } \mu(B)< \infty \right\}$ ,

$\mu(B_0) \leq \mu(A)=\mu(B_0)+\mu(A \backslash B_0) \leq \mu(B_0)+\mu(B_0)=2\mu(B_0) < \infty $.
If this was true we could say that $\mu(A)=\nu(A),  \forall A\in \mathcal{A}$.

I feel like i do not use the fact that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.
The problem is probably that $A \backslash B_0 \notin E$ thus $\mu(A \backslash B_0)$ is not an element we consider here.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Is it clear that mu and nu agree on all sets with finite mu-measure?  Then you just have to check that if A has infinite mu measure, A has infinite nu measure.

Comment: Yes, i think it's clear to me that if $\mu(A)< \infty$ then Sup $E=\nu(A)=\mu(A)$ and it's done. And if $\mu(A)=\infty$ we will have $\nu(A)= \infty$ but i'm not quite sure why.

Answer (score 1):

To show what you want, you can start observing that whenever $\mu(A) < \infty$, the equality holds. Then, you show that it holds for $\sigma$-finite sets, using $\sigma$-additivity. Then it hods for every set if the space is $\sigma$-additive.

I think you should search for an example where the equality fails, so you understand a bit better what is behind the phenomena.

For example, take an uncountable set. For example, $\mathbb{R}$. And take
$$\mu(A) = \begin{cases}0, &\text{ $A$ is countable}\\\infty &\text{ $A$ is uncountable.}\end{cases}$$

Then $\nu = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, then we have $X=\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n$  with $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \mu(A_n) < \infty$ with every $A_n$  two by two disjoint.

$\forall A \in \mathcal{A}, A =\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (A \bigcap  A_n)$,

$\mu(A) =\mu (\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (A \bigcap  A_n)) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \mu( A \bigcap A_n) \leq \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty  \mu(A_n)< \infty$ because $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \mu(\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{n} (A \bigcap  A_n))= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \mu(A \bigcap A_n)<\infty$
$   \mu (\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (A \bigcap  A_n)) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \mu( A \bigcap A_n)       \leq   $ Sup $ \mu (\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (A \bigcap  A_n))=$ Sup $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \mu( A \bigcap A_n) < \infty $. Thus $\mu(A)\leq \nu(A)$.

The other inequality is obvious, since $\nu(A)$ is defined as a supremum.

$\forall A,B \in \mathcal{A}, B \subset A \implies \mu(B) \leq \mu(A) \implies \nu(A) \leq \mu(A)$

Then $\forall A \in \mathcal{A}, \nu(A)=\mu(A) $

Is this correct ?